# Webservices in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, web-services

Does anyone know how to log the xml request sent by the classes created with WSMakeStubs?

I get the error

```
INFO  [STDOUT] DefaultValidationEventHandler: [ERROR]: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"getSectionsRequest"). Expected elements are (none)
```

Any input would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Radu

Comment: Posting some source code relevant to the problem would help.

Answer (score 1):

I think the service class has a BOOL field named logXMLInOut or like (this depends which tool you have used i.e. WSDL2OBJC or sudz). just set this to YES. This will work.